# Google Maps Viewport Marker Manager - Too Many Markers - JS API v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, viewport, marker

I have over 10,000 locations that I want to display on Google Maps.  The code below, works but it takes too long to load for all 10,000 locations.  Please help me change this code to use Viewport Marker Manager using this [weather map example](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/docs/examples.html)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();  

    var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Marker Manager does the job you need. Try [MarkerClusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach might be [Fusion Tables](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables). It was designed to handle large numbers of Markers.